# I need an example of comet refresh html when database is updated!

Tags: php, ajax, comet

People,

I am developing a web page that need to be refresh everytime that the data base gets an update. I already have the checkDatabaseUpdate() done in my PHP code.

But now I reaaly need some help to develop a simple comet to wait for a response, and another to check for update.

Is there anybody with any simple example to help me?

Is comet the right solution for that?

Thanks,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to say is that on the database are executed querys (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) in the backend and you want to refresh the front page of a user when that query`s are executed ?

Hmm .. use a jQuery (looping) to "Ajax check" for database update in the frontcontroller and then refresh.

```
function refreshPage () {
   $.load('checkModifDb.php', function(response, status) {
        if .... { do the trick here - check jquery load.api }
   }
});

and then use setInterval( "refreshPage()", 10000 ); to run the function every 10 seconds and 
refresh only if it founds that db was modified.
```

I can't think of anything right now but i guess with little modification you shoul do the trick. This is how twitter.com do it.

Comment: Or you could do it with `$.ajax` request and return a parameter, analyze it and initiate refersh of page if condition was met.

Answer (score 0):

> Is comet the right solution for that?

Because of the way that PHP works (having a web server daemon process incoming requests), combining it with long-polling techniques can make for an unhappy server.  Each connected user is going to hold open a connection to the web server daemon.  Depending on that daemon's configuration, you may find that comet is an effective denial of service attack against your own server.

You'd probably be better off with plain old short-lived ajax polling here.